# SOAP + WSDL + PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl

I need a litte bit help.
I have the following two URLS:

WSDL: https://amsel.dpwn.net/abholportal/gw/lp/schema/1.0/var3ws.wsdl

Endpoint: https://amsel.dpwn.net/abholportal/gw/lp/SoapConnector

Now I want to send the server something like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:var="https://amsel.dpwn.net/abholportal/gw/lp/schema/1.0/var3bl">
<soapenv:Header>
   <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1"
   xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-      secext-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:UsernameToken>
         <wsse:Username>ws_online_retoure</wsse:Username>
         <wsse:Password
         Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-tokenprofile1.0#
         PasswordText">Anfang1!</wsse:Password>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
   </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
   <var:BookLabelRequest
   portalId="OnlineRetoure"
   deliveryName="Spanien_Var3"
   shipmentReference="ShipRef Nextt"
   customerReference="1.Feld via Webservice"
   labelFormat="PDF"
   senderName1="Willi Webservice"
   senderName2="via Webservice"
   senderCareOfName="careOfName"
   senderContactPhone="0800 123456"
   senderStreet="Webservice Street"
   senderStreetNumber="8080"
   senderBoxNumber="12"
   senderPostalCode="28010"
   senderCity="Madrid"/>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How can I do this in PHP?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd like to know this too, SOAP Is the most annoying thing I've worked with, I'd like to know how to do something like this.

Comment: Check out the [PEAR library for SOAP](http://pear.php.net/package/SOAP/redirected).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the similar problem as well due to sparse examples on how to use SOAP with PHP. Here are a couple of examples that may guide you to developing the SOAP interface.

http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/phpajaxsoap/#IsSoapTheBestWay

http://geekswithblogs.net/THines01/archive/2010/03/07/callws.aspx

http://jimmyzimmerman.com/2007/02/soap-server-with-php5-part-1.html

SOAP is clearly an overkill for many purposes in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

See [NuSoap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/).

It simplifies the build of WebServices and clients.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But I don't get it how i connect to the urls and send the data. I need a simple example how I send the data.